# Device is showing not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping with the devices based on the `videoinput` .I want to display the values but here device is showing not defined. what I'm doing wrong here please help me thanks in advance

```
{
  devices.map((device, key) => device.kind ==="videoinput") 
  ? <option value={device.deviceId }> {device.label || `Device ${key + 1}`} </option>
  : null 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `)` after `"videoinput"` is ending the `devices.map()` call. The conditional expression needs to be part of the arrow function.

```
{
  devices.map((device, key) => device.kind ==="videoinput" ? 
    <option value={device.deviceId }> {device.label || `Device ${key + 1}`} </option>
    : null )
}
```